# Not able to call a wcf service from client

Tags: wcf

Getting an error "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Attempted to get contract type for ITC2DataService,
but that type is not a ServiceContract, nor does it inherit a ServiceContract.".

Note : I have already decorated the interface "ITC2DataService" with "ServiceContract" attribute. But still error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding ServiceContract to ITC2DataService, the service class also inherits derived contracts, such as the following :

```
public class Service1 : ITC2DataService
{
    ...
}
```

The corresponding endpoint binding in the Web.config file needs to specify the correct contract (like the endpoint address "ws" below).

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- ITestCallback needs to be the contract specified -->
    <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService.ITestCallback">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: jiayao - Thank you for your comment. Changes which you mentioned is already in the place. I have given the correct contract.But still issue exists.

Comment: How do you call the WCF client?

Comment: using (ServiceClient<ITC2DataService> _tc2DataServiceClient = new ServiceClient<ITC2DataService>("TC2DataServiceEndPoint")) 
            {
                _tc2DataServiceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ((ILogin)(HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginModel"])).UserName;
                modelList = _tc2DataServiceClient.Proxy.GetTC2Location(MAC, authDetails);
            }